# If we convert a value with one constructor, will there also be copy constructor needed to copy the newly created temp object?

Tags: c++, oop

I am having a trouble understanding the topic, and so it might be a stupid question but I am still wondering:

When we have a function, for example:

```
void func(const StringClass & param1, const StringClass & param2);
```

And then we pass to the function for example, a C string:

```
func("test", test);
```

Where `"test"` is a C string and `test` is an object of our `StringClass`.
And let's say our `StringClass` has defined a copy constructor and also a conversion constructor which can convert our `"test"` C string into a `StringClass` object. I have tested it already and what I have seen is that, that there is only conversion happening and not copying, and for the other object there is only assignment which I understand, since we pass it by reference. If our function is declared like this:

```
void func(const StringClass param1, const StringClass param2);
```

And we still pass previous arguments `func("test", test)`, then the first argument gets converted, but no copy constructor is invoked. And for the second parameter copy constructor is invoked.

But my question is - will it always be like that? I mean, can other compiler treat it like that: convert the `"test"` C string into a `StringClass` object and then use the copy constructor to copy the temp object to `param` argument inside the function, or a conversion is enough since it creates a temp object anyways, so it won't differ between compilers?

Comment: No. The compiler need to construct the parameter, which is of type StringClass. It is constructed from the argument. If the argument is another StringClass, then a copy constructor will be called. If the argument is a C-style string, then a conversion constructor will be called.

Comment: I see, so the copy constructor is called when we pass the StringClass object by value, not by reference, am I right?

Comment: Right. When passing by const reference, something else happens. The argument does not get constructed from the parameter, instead it binds to the parameter. If the type matches, it just binds and no new object gets created. Otherwise, a temporary is created from the argument and the parameter binds to it. In this case, no copy is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first hint you can add a copy constructor that prints something to see if it gets called:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    template <size_t n>
    foo(const char(&str)[n]){
        std::cout << "converting constructor\n";
    }
    foo(const foo& f){
        std::cout << "copy constructor\n";
    }
};

void bar(foo){}

int main() {
    bar("asdf");
}
```

[Output is](https://godbolt.org/z/99eMaWr8a):

```
converting constructor
```

No copy constructor is called in this example. This is only a hint, because it is the output with one specific compiler and one specific C++ standard. However, once a `foo` has been created by calling the converting constructor, there is no reason to call the copy constructor. The string literal `"asdf"` is converted to a `foo` and thats it. There is no additional copy in the code, hence no compiler should create another copy.

Comment: Wow, I have thought that by analogy, we have, for example:

StringClass obj1 = obj2; and then copy constructor is invoked and copied to obj1, so I have thought, that if we write:

StringClass obj1 = "test", then the conversion constructor is invoked and then the copy constructor is invoked, since we have still not copied the insides of newly created object on the right side. But it seems that conversion constructor actually handles the assignment to the memory of StringClass obj1. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: @todovvox a constructor already creates an object, be it a copy constructor or a converting constructor, there is no need to make another copy